# Replacing the Weight-of-Evidence (WoE) with its corresponding value

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have variable called `x` whose minimum value is zero and maximum is 2 million. So I cut the value into bins like this code:

```
bins = [0,1,10000,20000,50000,60000,70000,100000,2000000]
df_input['X_bins'] = pd.cut(df_input['X'], bins,right=False)
```

[image]

Currently I am using for-loop to replace each bin with their Weight-of-Evidence value:

```
def flag_dfstd(df_input):
    if (df_input['X'] >=0) & (df_input['X'] <100) :
        return '-0.157688'
    elif (df_input['X'] >=100) & (df_input['X'] < 10000) :
        return '-0.083307'
    elif (df_input['X'] >=10000) & (df_input['X'] < 20000) :
        return '0.381819'
    elif (df_input['X'] >=20000) & (df_input['X'] < 50000):
        return '0.364365'
    else:
        return '0'
df_input['X_WOE'] = df_input.apply(flag_dfstd, axis = 1).astype(str)
```

Is there way that I can replace the Weight of Evidence without using for loop?

Comment: Is there way that i can replace the weight of evidence with out using for loop

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with parameter `labels` and for replace misisng value is necessary add [`cat.add_categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html) before replace:

```
df_input = pd.DataFrame({'X':[0,20,100, 10000, 30000, 1000000]})

b = [-np.inf, 100, 10000, 20000, 50000]
l = ['-0.157688', '-0.083307', '0.381819', '0.364365']

df_input['X_WOE'] = pd.cut(df_input['X'], bins=b, labels=l,right=False)
df_input['X_WOE'] = df_input['X_WOE'].cat.add_categories(['0']).fillna('0')
print (df_input)
         X      X_WOE
0        0  -0.157688
1       20  -0.157688
2      100  -0.083307
3    10000   0.381819
4    30000   0.364365
5  1000000          0
```