# In python, how to bin ranges based on look up table with lower and upper limits

Tags: python, pandas

EDIT: This question was marked as duplicate, but I looked at the solution of the other question and it doesn't quite solve my issue. So this is not a duplicate.

I have a dataset with numeric variables that I want to map them to the Weight of Evidence stored in a look up table. Below is an example, but I have a lot of variables to transform. How can I automate this? I have done this in the past using SAS and SQL, but dont know how to do this in Python? I searched the internet but found examples using pd.cut. However, it requires us to manually code the bin ranges. I am not sure how to automate this. I want the lower limit to be greater than or equal to (>=) and upper limit to be less than (<).

I wrote a code down below. I get an error in the mask statement. Can you please let me know what is wrong with the code? Thanks.

```
temp_dict = {'var1': [4, 2, 2, 4, 7, 4, 12, 8, 17, 42, 33, 10, 7, 5, 17, 29, 64, 20, 39, 6], 
             'var2': [9, 8, 2, 17, 14, 14, 16, 8, -999999999,-999999999, 10, -999999999, 16, 20, 17,
                      -999999999, -999999999, -999999999,-999999999, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp_dict)
```

Look up table:

| Index | feature_name | lower_limit | upper_limit | WoE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | var1 | -999999990 | 1.5 | 1.363071 |
| 1 | var1 | 1.5 | 2.5 | 1.231135 |
| 2 | var1 | 2.5 | 3.5 | 0.819431 |
| 3 | var1 | 3.5 | 14.5 | 0.617399 |
| 4 | var1 | 14.5 | 15.5 | -0.62779 |
| 5 | var1 | 15.5 | 20.5 | -0.706259 |
| 6 | var1 | 20.5 | 999999990 | -0.950134 |
| 7 | var1 | -999999999 | -999999999 | 0 |
| 8 | var1 | NaN | NaN | 0 |
| 0 | var2 | -999999990 | 0.5 | 0.951202 |
| 1 | var2 | 0.5 | 1.5 | 0.427215 |
| 2 | var2 | 1.5 | 2.5 | 0.218994 |
| 3 | var2 | 2.5 | 3.5 | 0.026722 |
| 4 | var2 | 3.5 | 13.5 | -0.071878 |
| 5 | var2 | 13.5 | 999999990 | -1.615368 |
| 6 | var2 | -999999999 | -999999999 | 0 |
| 7 | var2 | NaN | NaN | 0 |

Desired result:

| var1 | var2 | WoE_var1 | WoE_var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 9 | 0.617399 | -0.071878 |
| 2 | 8 | 1.231135 | -0.071878 |
| 2 | 2 | 1.231135 | 0.218994 |
| 4 | 17 | 0.617399 | -1.615368 |
| 7 | 14 | 0.617399 | -1.615368 |

Edit:

I figured this out. Here is the code.

```
binned_vars= ['var1','var2'..'varn']
short_list= ['var1','var2']
for variable in binned_vars:
    if variable in short_list:
        for i in lookup_table[(lookup_table['feature_name'] == variable)]['Index'].to_list():
            lower_limit = lookup_table[(lookup_table['feature_name'] == variable) & (lookup_table['Index'] == i)]['lower_limit'].to_list()[0]
            upper_limit = lookup_table[(lookup_table['feature_name'] == variable) & (lookup_table['Index'] == i)]['upper_limit'].to_list()[0]
            WoE = lookup_table[(lookup_table['feature_name'] == variable) & (lookup_table['Index'] == i)]['WoE'].to_list()[0]  
            mask = ((df[variable] >= lower_limit) & (df[variable] < upper_limit))
            var_name = variable + '_WoE'
            df.loc[mask,var_name] = WoE
```

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60892714/how-to-get-the-weight-of-evidence-woe-and-information-value-iv-in-python

Comment: So two options are to make your lookup table have an interval index from `lower_limit` and `upper_limit` and index into it with your feature columns.  The other would be repeated `merge_asof` between your feature columns and your lookup table.  There might be some issue with the NaN values there though.

Comment: This link shows how to calculate WoE and Information Value. In my case, it is already precalculated based on another training dataset to which I don't have access. However, the look up table has the values and the bin lower and upper limit. I want to just use this to map the WoE using the ranges. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You don't need to manually do `lookup_table`, that functionality is provided by [`pd.cut()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html). And see [Replacing the Weight of evidence with their value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59233546/202229)